# How do I open Action Center ---> Connect in Windows 10 for testing?

Tags: windows, ui-automation, python-appium

I'm writing an UI test automation for an app connecting laptop screen to TV. I need to open Connect through Action Center to see the list of available receivers. I'm using Appium in Python to test the app but the thing is Appium doesn't support Desktop app. So is there any way that I can open Connect in Action Center panel automatically? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm surprised that after 3+ years, nobody has responded to this question...*

Anyhow, to assist others who may be wondering how to open **Action Center > Connect** in Windows 10, you can launch this URI from a command-prompt (cmd.exe):

`start ms-settings-connectabledevices:devicediscovery`

Otherwise, from a PowerShell session:

`Start-Process -FilePath ms-settings-connectabledevices:devicediscovery`

Or, simply from Windows 10 **Start Menu > Run...**

`ms-settings-connectabledevices:devicediscovery`

*I'll leave it to others to determine how to invoke this from Appium in Python.*